# Magnetic field generation

Tags: magnetic-fields, charge

The magnetic field is generated by means of moving charges (let it be point charges moving through a region in space or a wire with some intensity). I read that magnetic fields are generated by moving charges only, is this true, or there is another way of generating a magnetic field or this is just restricted to moving charges as the Lorentz force describes

Comment: electron spin is the source of all permanent ferromagnetism, no moving charge is involved.

Comment: @hyportnex Hmmm. The magnetic momentum of fundamental particles arise when charge is coupled with a non-zero angular momentum. And you can say the same about the magnetic moment associated with orbital angular momentum. They do without "motion" is a classical sense, but still result from charge and quantities naively associated with motion.

Comment: @dmckee I believe the OP would like to visualize what macroscopic motion of a charged particle would lead to magnetism. My point above was that ferromagnetism does not involve that kind of motion and it appears that you agree with that. There is no way to explain (or even illustrate) using classical physics language the *causes* of ferromagnetism that is essentially a macroscopic scale quantum mechanical phenomenon, so I think we should just leave it that way without causing more confusion.